# How to use AzureRm module with PowerShell 7?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-core

**Context**

I've just installed PowerShell 7. I am trying to run my working tested Azure related scripts... So I installed and imported AzureAd and AzureRM modules.

When trying to log in either `Connect-AzureAD` or `Connect-AzureRmAccount`both gave me the following error (keep reading)

> Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng'

OK, this is because the Azure Modules are looking for that API, which is not available in .NET Core, so I used the `Import-Module` with the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` parameter, which solved the issue **but only for the AzureAD module**

**Question**

For the command `Import-Module AzureRm -UseWindowsPowerShell` I got the following error message:

> Import-Module: Failed to generate proxies for remote module 'AzureRM'. Running the Get-Command command in a remote session returned no results.

So I still can not use `Connect-AzureRmAccount` Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `AzureRm` is incompatible with PowerShell 7, and it has been deprecated and will not be updated.

Your option is to use the `Az` module, just uninstall the `AzureRm` module and  install the `Az` module.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Force
```

Fore more details, see [Introducing the new Azure PowerShell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0).

Then use the `Connect-AzAccount` to login, if you don't want to change your existing script which uses `AzureRm` command, just use `Enable-AzureRmAlias` before all the commands.